# Cloud Service: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0'

Tags: .net, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have deployed a project to Azure by creating a package from Visual Studio and importing it in the Azure Portal.
The deployment succeeds, but the instances stay in the 'Busy' state.

I've connected to an instance via remote desktop and I see the error below.

Unless I am mistaken, I am not supposed to include the System.Runtime library myself. On top of that, the version in my GAC is 4.0.0.0. I have installed the latest versions of Visual Studio, Azure SDK etc.
The project itself is targeting .Net framework 4.5

I'm at a loss why the cloud service is expecting System.Runtime 4.1.0.0...
Any help will be appreciated!

```
Log Name:      Windows Azure
Source:        Windows Azure Runtime 2.7.0.0
Date:          10/11/2017 10:33:54 AM
Event ID:      2001
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      ***
Description:
An unhandled exception occurred. Type: System.IO.FileNotFoundException Process ID: 3252
Process Name: WaIISHost
Thread ID: 5
AppDomain Unhandled Exception for role ***
Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at ***.***.WebRole.OnStart()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRoleInternal(RoleType roleTypeEnum)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.<InitializeRole>b__0()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()


Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Windows Azure Runtime 2.7.0.0" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">2001</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>1</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-10-11T10:33:54.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>726</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Windows Azure</Channel>
    <Computer>***</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>System.IO.FileNotFoundException</Data>
    <Data>Process ID: 3252
Process Name: WaIISHost
Thread ID: 5
AppDomain Unhandled Exception for role ***
Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at ***.***.WebRole.OnStart()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRoleInternal(RoleType roleTypeEnum)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.&lt;InitializeRole&gt;b__0()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: [System.Runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime/4.1.0) represents the core package. What packages are you using in your project, could you provide the `packages.config`? Moreover, does your cloud project could run as expected on your local side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that for some reason, there was some Core stuff added to my project. I reverted my project file back to an older version and reincluded all my code changes. Then the package would run on the cloud service again.